# Why can't I remove a directory on Windows Server 2012R2?

Tags: windows, permissions

I've got a folder that I created a few months ago on a secondary drive (E:) on one of our servers.  It was shared for a user (and part of DFS).  I've since removed the DFS entry for it as well as the sharing on it.  I deleted all the contents, but am unable to delete the folder itself.  From the CMD prompt I get a generic "Access Denied".  From Explorer it tells me that I need to get permission from myself.  I click OK, and then access denied...  The folder has myself and administrator listed as full control.  I'm shown as the owner of the folder.  I've done a CMD prompt as administrator and access is still denied.  I've rebooted and the results are the same afterwards.  Any ideas on what's going on with this folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was finally able to delete the folder by first changing the ownership of it to a less privileged user.  Then an admin level user deletion went through without any issue.